# objc_class$____ error

Tags: iphone

For my application i need to work with calendar.
 `http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244` from this link i downloaded required stuff.....

related to calendar....  now i need to import it into my application.

Even i added all the required framework in my application. its showing me error...

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CheckmarkTile", referenced from:

Any one help me out. What to do..

Answer (score 2):

This _OBJC_CLASS_$_ Error comes if you dont include the framework for that corresponding Object class. In your case  this CheckmarkTile.

If you have included this calendar component in your project. Then rightclick frameworks group in xcode add Existing Frameworks. The Select AddOther and include the build file of that calendar project. Now Clean Build and run.

Or Just try this

Just include the ChemarkTile .h and .m files into your project and then clean build

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's added to your target to compile. As stated above...

**Just include the ChemarkTile .h and .m files into your project and then clean build**